# Align camera based on two images

Tags: camera, image

I have two images of a scene from google maps; one is a top-down orthographic view, the other one a perspective view. How can I align the camera against the orthographic view so that it looks like the perspective view? I've been fiddling with the camera settings for hours, rotating the plane, moving the focal point around, and I can't get the two images to even closely resemble eachother. I even tried using BLAM, and that didn't give a much better result than what I had already.

Is there a way I can just select 5 or so points on each image and have a program automatically solve the camera coordinates to make them both match up? That would solve my problem easily.

Here is a link to the images i'm trying to align, as well as how I'm trying to go about doing it; https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zMyG.jpg

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of what you are trying to do in blender as well as the two pics, since in my mind I would think to only use one camera angle to solve for a single camera.

Comment: Added some images.

Comment: I see now what you mean -  but the fact is that those are two different cameras anyway, so they won't even probably solve the same. I used a few different cameras to model from, one for each picture and set each in position manually to a single cube until I got the cube to match correctly enough to make sure I was going to model to proper relative scale. Of course, each photo had to be made to the same size pixel wise so that the camera settings for render matched.